# Load historical data from an API into snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to GET historical data from an API and store it in snowflake table. To get one day's data from the API take 1.5 minutes. Writing into snowflake is taking only a fraction of a second. I have to hit the API multiple times to get a day's data. I prepare a consolidated JSON with it and writes into snowflake table. As I am trying to get 1 year's worth of data, my process may take ~10 hours. How can I reduce the processing time? Is there a way I can perform parallel processing to reduce the processing time? I tried to use collect_nowait method. However, the process failed. Apparently, snowflake doesn't support async processing in procedures. I am using snowpark procedure and realized that async operations are not permitted in it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi - so which is the slow step, getting the data from the API or writing it to Snowflake? Whichever one it is, you’ll need to add a lot more information to your question before anyone can help you

Comment: Thanks for the nudge @nickw. I updated more details in my question.

Comment: The issue appears with your API calls and not so much snowflake.   If your API calls can be made in parallel, then I would suggestion doing that and combining the contents into a new file that you then just upload the 1 file.

Comment: If that’s the time the api takes to return data then there’s not a lot you can do about it - assuming you have no influence over the owner of the api. You can try parallel calls but you may find that the api developer has put throttling in place - specifically so that you can’t do this and swamp their system

Comment: @Sorceri, to fetch 1 day's data, I have to hit the API ~2000 times and append it in a single JSON. I can make parallel calls to the API for multiple days. But I don't think I can do it in parallel and write the output in output file/s in non-parallel mode. Please note that I am thinking about this logic in a snowflake procedure.

Comment: @AnandRajakrishnan , with regard to historical data ,directly loading from api to Snowflake wouldn’t be right design, can you not bring this historical data into intermediate layer like stage and subsequently load into Snowflake from this stage.

Comment: @akshindesnowflake, I can write into S3 and consume the S3 files using "COPY INTO" or "INSERT INTO". Still the issue of the process taking long time is not addressed by this method.

Comment: It wouldn’t be automatically taken care by this design , you have to split the files into multiple chunks ;ideal size is between 100-250 mb as recommended by snowflake ,  this way snowflake brings parallel processing to data load when you use copy into.